# windows batch file script to extract third line from all text files in a directory

Tags: windows, text, batch-file

I need a a windows batch script file to extract the third line from all text files in a directory and output them on a separate text file. Can anyone help me write a batch file to extract this information? I am a rank beginner at this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It is doable, but only with a small hack.

First, you need to create a batch file `thirdline.cmd`:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%i in (%1) do echo %%i & goto :EOF
```

Then, *from the command line* you would do:

```
for %i in (*.*) do @thirdline "%i"
```

If you want to do this from inside another batch file, you 'll need to change the `%i` above to `%%i` (i.e. as they appear in `thirdline.cmd`).

Remember to replace `*.*` with the filemask that matches the files you want to process.

Finally, `thirdline.cmd` as given above just outputs the third line to the console. If you want to write it to another file (let's say `lines.txt`), change `thirdline.cmd` to:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%i in (%1) do >>lines.txt echo %%i & goto :EOF
```

Comment: @Jon I am sorry but I don't know how to follow the instructions you wrote above. I am a total dummy when it comes to this. Can you write a code where I save to a text file and name it something.bat, put it to the same directory as the files I'd like to extract text from and double click it and voila. I'm sorry for being such a noob. I'll learn this soon but for now this thing is urgent.

Comment: @techdaemon: I 've already given instructions that will get you 99% of the way, and have no desire to act as a helpdesk.

Comment: in other words, you are just plain lazy. Jon has given you enough information for you to work on. He is not there to do your work entirely for you.

Comment: @Jon and @kurumi it took some time for me to get Jon's instructions. Not that I'm lazy but I'm not just good at this. So I opened cmd and changed dir to where my files are. The command doesn't work and I think it's because of the spaces and special characters in the filenames. What should I do?

Comment: @techdaemon: Use `for %i in (*.*) do @thirdline "%i"` (added quotes around `%i`)

Comment: thanks but still it didnt work. what i did instead was change the filenames of my text files (with the help of total commander) to remove spaces and special chars and used the `for %i in (*.*) do @thirdline %i` (without quotes) and it worked! Is there no way to combine the cmd file and the command entered on cmd to make one bat file that can be run so I can save time in a similar task next time? I tried it but to no avail.

Comment: @techdaemon: It is *possible*. But it is easier to put the command in another batch file (making the change from `%i` to `%%i`) and run that one, keeping both files together at all times.

Comment: Note though, that this will skip empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

Merely as an alternative, here's another approach:

```
SETLOCAL
(FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,3) DO SET /P line=) < filename.txt
> another.txt ECHO %line%
ENDLOCAL
```

Use `SETLOCAL` & `ENDLOCAL` whenever you can't be sure if the variables you are going to introduce with your script will not collide with the already existing ones, either defined by the system or brought along by a calling batch script, if any. Basically, use them just to be on the safe side. (Thanks Jon for the suggestion!)

Comment: +1: *Very* very nice! I would totally not have thought of this! If I may suggest an improvement: `SETLOCAL`/`ENDLOCAL`.

Comment: @Jon: Thank you. I think I'm not really familiar with `SETLOCAL`/`ENDLOCAL`, even though I know what they are for in theory. I mean I don't see why they are needed (or would bring any improvement) here. There may be some subtleties about them I'm not aware of. (Or maybe something fairly basic I fail to see.)

Comment: To avoid overwriting or polluting the environment with the `line` variable.

Comment: @Jon: Well, that is basic all right. :) Point taken, answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice, here's a [Ruby for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) one liner

```
$ ruby -ne "ARGF.lineno=0 if ARGF.eof?; print if ARGF.lineno==3" *.txt
```

Comment: I don't know how to use ruby. I'm a complete noob. I'm serious. Is there not something for a a bat script?

Comment: download and install. then run it like that from the command line. nothing that difficult. You are a beginner at batch too.